# Calculation of product of two independent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Given the independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the following pdf:

\begin{align*}
f_x(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}x\sigma}e^{-\frac{(\ln(x)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}},\quad \text{with }x\in(0,+\infty)\\[5pt]
f_y(y)&=\frac{Q}{(r-p)^2}y^{-2}-\frac{r\sqrt{Q}}{(r-p)^2}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}\quad\text{with } Q,p,r>0, r>q, y\in\left(\frac{Q}{r^2},\frac{Q}{p^2}\right).
\end{align*}
I have to calculate the pdf of $Z=XY$.
I am using the following formula:

$$f_z(z)=\int^{\infty}_0f_x(x)f_y\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

Note that the integration is from $0$ to infinity as this is the range where $x$ is defined.

I obtain a closed form result of the previous integral, which however does not represent a pdf as the integral $\int^{\infty}_0f_z(z)\,dz$ diverges.
Any suggestion on what I might be doing wrong?